# Custom UIBarButtonItem keep Aspect Ratio for Image but Space out Buttons

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am adding some custom image UIBarButtonItems to my navigation bar. If I do not mess with the item.width property, then my buttons are too close together, but if I space them out with the width property, then the button image is distorted. How can I maintain the aspect ratio of the button image but space out my custom items?

[image]

[image]

```
    // Create custom map button
    UIButton *mapButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [mapButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [mapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissMapView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [mapButton setFrame:CGRectMake(280, 25, 30, 30)];
    UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:mapButton];
    button1.width = (self.drawer.frame.size.width / 5.0f); // Space it out a bit

    // Create custom list button
    UIButton *listButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [listButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [listButton addTarget:self action:@selector(scrollToRow:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [listButton setFrame:CGRectMake(280, 25, 30, 30)];
    UIBarButtonItem *button2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:listButton];
    button2.width = (self.drawer.frame.size.width / 5.0f); // Space it out a bit

    // Add buttons to drawer
    self.drawer.items = @[button1,button2];
```

Comment: set UIButton ImageEdgeInset .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code for adding custom bar button in `navigationbar`.

```
        UIImage* image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"compose_message_button.png"];
        CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(250, 9, 43,32);
        UIButton *SettingButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
        [SettingButton setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [SettingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnWriteMessage:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [SettingButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
        UIBarButtonItem *mailbutton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:SettingButton];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=mailbutton;
        [SettingButton release];
```

i hope this code is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create some explicit spacer items using `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace`.

Or you could create your bar buttons with custom views (`initWithCustomView:`) and then you can lay the content views out as you like.